# Account Setting Checkbox

Tags: account, checkbox

is there any way to know who and when modifies the "Enable Automated Account Fields" Checkbox in Account Settings?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe, check setup audit trails from setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can check using [View Setup Audit Trail](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_monitorsetup.htm&type=5) and for 'Enable Automated Account Fields ' you would see changes with 'lightningAccSuggestionPrefOffOn' in audit logs.

[image]

Thanks